# How to draw any right angled triangle with turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How to specify angles?

```py
def isosceles(a, b):
    side =sqrt(a ** 2 + b ** 2)
    turtle.forward(b)
    ???
    turtle.forward(side)
```

Comment: Please don't show your code as an image. Just copy your code as text and paste it into your question.

Comment: If you could specify coordinates of the vertices you could use answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424967/how-to-draw-shapes-in-python-turtle-using-a-list-of-coordinates)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to calculate the length of the hypotenuse (or an internal angle) if you can just return to an origin:

```
import turtle

def isosceles(a, b):
    origin = turtle.pos()
    turtle.forward(a)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(b)
    turtle.goto(origin)

isosceles(30,40)
```

Comment: ok, thank you a lot
but i have to use tan during the solving

Comment: So, how does tan come into it?

Answer (score 1):

If you ware to do try this I would eiter try the origins function to.
Or if you need or want to work with the degree you could try the following:

```py
from math import atan2, degrees
import turtle


def isosceles(a, b, man=True):
    origin = turtle.pos()
    turtle.forward(a)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(b)
    if man: # origin solution
        turtle.goto(origin)
    else: # manual solution
        side = sqrt(a ** 2 + b ** 2)
        angle = degrees(atan2(a / b))
        turtle.left(180 - angle)
        turtle.forward(side)
```