# How to draw a polygon given a number of points with Turtle Library?

Tags: turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm learning Python using the Turtle Library.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html

I have a list of points given by `(x, y)` coordinates, and I want to connect them in a polygon shape. For example:

```py
import turtle
    
tina = turtle.Turtle()
tina.shape('turtle')
    
points = [
    (40, -80),
    (30, -80),
    (30, -70),
    (40, -70)
]
```

How do I draw a polygon using lines and these points?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What's your question? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: you will have to do some mathematical calculation in turtle

Comment: You may find it convenient to adjust the viewport: `ll = (20, -90)`; `ur = (50, -60)`;
`turtle.Screen().setworldcoordinates(*ll, *ur)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw shapes in Python/turtle using a list of coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424967/how-to-draw-shapes-in-python-turtle-using-a-list-of-coordinates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import turtle

tina=turtle.Turtle()
tina.shape("turtle")

points=[[10,-80],[200,-80], [100, 100]]

# Draw a polygon based on the points list in points and #show the result
def draw_polygon(points):
    tina.penup()
    tina.goto(points[0])
    tina.pendown()
    for point in points:
        tina.goto(point)

    tina.goto(points[0])  # Go back to the origin to close the polygon shape


draw_polygon(points)

turtle.done()
```

However, it draws only in the order the points are given - so that order needs to be correctly specified in order to get a polygon.

Comment: [filling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.end_fill) is also worth pointing out.